# MongoDB Padding Clarification

Tags: mongodb, padding

Looking through the usage of [capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) with MongoDB a question came to mind over the following statement:

> "You can update documents in a collection after inserting them. However, these updates
>   **cannot** cause the documents to grow. If the update operation causes the document
>   to grow beyond their original size, the update operation will fail."

So this by itself sounds reasonable, if not entirely explained for the reasons why. And it leads me to ponder, "If I don't want the document to grow, but possibly add more information (ie: $push to an array) , then what would be wrong with padding the document to my expected size."

So again my premise would sound reasonable (to me anyway), right up until reading this fragment from the [FAQ on padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#can-i-manually-pad-documents-to-prevent-moves-during-updates).

> **Warning** Do not manually pad documents in a capped collection. Applying manual
>   padding to a document in a capped collection can break replication. Also, the padding
>   is not preserved if you re-sync the MongoDB instance.

And again this raises my question, "Why is this so?" Or to put it specifically:

1. Why would padding a document in a capped collection in this wasy "break replication"?
2. Is there a missed section of the documentation stating the obvious reasons for this? Or is this just "Dark Magic" of the capped collection inner workings at work? (Probably linked to the "padding is not preserved" part)
3. Or is this just being very pessimistic and there is actually no reason you could not pad in this way? (At least in recent versions).

Would be glad if someone could shed some light on why these statements are true.

P.S While this isn't *strictly* programming I considered the *manual padding* technique to be a *programming technique*, and hence left the question here.

Comment: I believe it is because the secondaries have no knowledge of your manual padding. It doesn't go down the oplog

Answer (score 2):

> Why would padding a document in a capped collection in this wasy "break replication"?

I think that the documentation might be a little overcautious (see [DOCS-1528](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-1528)) here. MongoDB has no way of knowing whether the field `padding_foobar` is used for 'manual padding' or contains system critical information, so that technique generally works, *BUT*

The **caveat** is this: MongoDB *initial* replication will always pack the data tightly, so when the initial replication happens *after* you changed the size of the document, you'll later be unable to *grow* the document again.

An example (NOTE: I will use only the content size here, that's not correct, because the field names, type ids, terminators and string lengths also take up space, but that only strengthens the argument):

```
// 1. insert w/ 20 bytes of 'content'
insert({"name" : "john", "pad" : "0000000000000000"});

// 2. now we're performing an update, removing 16 bytes of padding, adding
//    3 bytes so we now have 7 bytes of 'content'
update({"name" : "john"}, {$unset: {"pad": 1}, $set: {"foo" : "bar"}});

// 3. at this point, we can easily grow the document again, as long as it doesn't
//    grow past its original size of 20 bytes of content
update({"name" : "john"}, {$set: {"foo" : "barfoobar"}});
```

Now when initial replication occurred after step 2), The document is replicated without the padding field so it's only 7 bytes of 'content size' on the replica. In that case, the operation in **step 3) will fail** because it grows the document past the replica's "original size" of the document which doesn't match the original size of the master's document.

In other words, the technique is fine if and only if your updates are strictly keeping or decreasing the object size. Whether you can ensure that in your application logic or not (e.g. because there's only a single update on such a document, ever) is something only you can answer.

Comment: Nicely structured answer. But unless I have ("bottle of wine") dropped a lot of IQ points how does this not strengthen point **3** from my original statement? Unless what you are really saying is that **somewhere** the "padding" phase is being skipped. Which in my mind id kind of *counter productive* to replication concepts, if not **all** ops are being replayed. So if that **is** the case it still doesn't seem right.

Comment: Like I wrote, the doc wants you be cautious (read the discussion in the referenced Jira ticket), so yes, you can do it (that's also what I'm saying in the last paragraph), but remember that initial replica set sync *will* break this. So if you have to add a third replica after a year of operation or a replica breaks, it will fail unless you copied the data files manually and the files are there before any doc is shrunk. That makes the abstraction extremely leaky (devops must understand and know about this). In more technical terms, initial replica set sync breaks the idempotency of the oplog.

Comment: First of all, sorry for the sound of tumbleweeds on this but is was my hope that the issue would attract more attention from involved people, and particularly the MongoDB employees who frequent here. And by that I mean, "at least in a comment". While it is true that your "last sentence" in the proceeding comment hold the most weight in the reasoning of this, my logic is that in the "spirit" of the question we are talking about a "capped collection", and as such an **edge case** like this **should not** be valid for general usage. The premise remains sound, that the warning is FUD. No offence.

Comment: So just trying to document that **outside of the edge case** you **can** use operators such as $push on documents in a capped collection. As the general use case is that the documents **should** be short lived. Any other error handling **should** be up to the developer.

Comment: If you want to reach the MongoDB developers, you could use the link to the Jira I posted. I'd be careful to declare initial replica set sync an 'edge case'. It seems you're looking for someone who tells you "just go ahead and don't worry", but I won't be that guy.

Comment: Actually I'm not looking for that. What I am saying is that the documentation point is too harsh. The current FUD is that you **cannot** do what I asked about. "Use $push on an array in a capped collection" at all. The thinking is that is you **take care** then you can do it. Go ahead and google it. Most responses say, "no you can't" without any clarification.

Comment: DOCS describe a technique that's valid for regular collections, but will break in replication. In fact, the only updates that should be legal for capped collections are ones that do not change the size of the document, and this is described in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6984 there are many other tickets linked to that one showing it's a real problem.  Luckily it looks like it will be fixed for 2.7 (by forbidding such an update).